# Make files publicly readable, but not whole bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sdk

I'm uploading files from my server to my bucket `foobar`. The path of the uploaded file is `foobar/uploads/avatars/123456789.jpg`.

I want users to be able to access this file via a public https link like https://storage.googleapis.com/foobar/uploads/avatars/123456789.jpg. The link has to be accessible without logging into any google account.
I **do not** want users to be able to browse the whole bucket by a link like https://storage.googleapis.com/foobar/, https://storage.googleapis.com/foobar/uploads/avatars/ or somehow different.

I am using [@google-cloud/storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) to upload the files. How can I achieve these settings with ACL?

Answer (score 3):

For an existing object:

```
file.makePublic(function(err, apiResponse) {});
```

When uploading a new object, use the option `public`, which is the equivalent of specifying `options.predefinedAcl = 'publicRead'`. Depending on how you're doing the upload, you might change your `createWriteStream` call like so:

```
file.createWriteStream({public: true, metadata: {...}})
```